# Wordpress error log not working

Tags: php, wordpress

i try to insert use this code below to wp-config.php before `/* That's all, stop editing! Happy blogging. */`
to show wordpress error log but still nothing anyone help me pls?

```
// Enable WP_DEBUG mode
define('WP_DEBUG', true);

// Enable Debug logging to the /wp-content/debug.log file
define('WP_DEBUG_LOG', true);

// Disable display of errors and warnings 
define('WP_DEBUG_DISPLAY', false);

@ini_set('display_errors',0);
```

Comment: You can add ini_set('log_errors', 1); and check

Comment: no it still not working

Comment: Check your folder permissions first.Also, be sure about chmod ing the folders correctly, e.g. wordpress needs to be able to have write access to that folder ,

Comment: i run in my local machine using wampserver

Comment: If you see any error when you have debug mode on?

Comment: i turn on all define('WP_DEBUG', true);

Comment: let see my code below

Comment: are you sure that there must be any error ? because without errors/warnings/notices or handly written errors you shouldn't see `debug.log` file( it'll not create )

Comment: i tried to make function and syntax error but i got HTTP ERROR 500 i want to see error msg